# Path Variable using AngularJS and Spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am trying to make simple page with Hello and name user using PathVariable. Well, if you come on http://localhost:8080/#/John you will see on site "Hello John".

I know good Java, but in AngularJS I'm beginner. well i think its problem.

HelloController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{name}")
public class HelloController {


@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String name(@PathVariable String name) {
    return this.name(name);
}


@RequestMapping("/layout")
public String getHomePage(ModelMap modelMap) {
    return "hello/layout";
}
}
```

HelloController in angular

```
var HelloController = function($scope, $http) {

var name = $name;
$scope.name = function(name) {

    $http.get(name).success(function() {
    })

};}
```

app.js

```
var AngularSpringApp = {};

var App = angular.module('AngularSpringApp', ['AngularSpringApp.filters',         'AngularSpringApp.services', 'AngularSpringApp.directives']);

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {


$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home/layout',
    controller: HomeController
});

$routeProvider.when('/:name', {
    templateUrl: 'hello/layout',
    controller: HelloController
 });
 }]);
```

Simple page hello/layout.html

```
 <div class="alert alert-error" ng-show="error">{{errorMessage}}</div>
 <form class="form-horizontal">

  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
 </form>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract name from URL when angularJS is loaded and bind it with name scope variable.

```
angular.module('sortApp', [])

            .controller('mainController', function($scope,$window) {
     $scope.name=$window.location.href.split("#/")[1];
     console.log($scope.name);
});
```

then bind it using {{name}} in HTML

Comment: when you are running this code, open console (google chrome's) and tell what is the output? I mean i want to know the result of console.log() line.

Comment: i have made changes in the code, i forgot to add $window in controller function, my bad i have made changes in code. Try now.